# How to define a set of CSS class names so Vim knows how to autocomplete

Tags: css, vim, autocomplete

Mostly, I'm very happy the way Vim autocompletes words for me. Currently, I'm working in a HTML/CML/Javascript/CSS framework, that uses a defined set of CSS class names to style an application. Class names like eg

```
  Framework_Table
  FrameWork_NumberInput
  Framework_TextOutput
```

which one would use like

```
  .Framework_Table {}
  .FrameWork_NumberInput {}
  .Framework_TextOutput {}
```

Question is, how/where do I list these class names to Vim's autocomplete can pick them up?

Comment: If they are already somewhere in an open buffer, `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` should be able to catch them.

Comment: Of course. But I'd like to see the entire set of CSS identifiers be auto-completed, not just the subset in use in open buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dictionary-based completion.

1. Put all your identifiers in a file, say `/path/to/project/cssdict.txt`.

   ```
   Framework_Table
   FrameWork_NumberInput
   Framework_TextOutput
   ```
2. In Vim, do `:setlocal dictionary=/path/to/project/cssdict.txt`.
3. Hit `<C-x><C-k>` to complete using that dictionary.

Read `:help 'dictionary'` and `:help compl-dictionary`.