# Toggle a window with the contents of a file and folding

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is there a plugin for Vim that can open a window with the contents of a file in the style Tagbar do?

The only difference with the behaviour of Tagbar is that when hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> over the element, Vim inserts the element in the document (previous windows before the jump to Toggle window).

For example imagine I am writing a Math document. I want to have a file called symbols that, in some way, I can tell

**Functions symbols (with fold posibility)**

```
integral
derivative
plus minus
```

**Greek letters (with folding as ToggleBar)**

```
alpha
beta
gamma
```

So, when I type ToggleMath, a toggle window appear with that content and when I hit alpha, an alpha is written in my document.

** EDIT - ANSWER **

I have looked into the first post @romainl pointed out. The best solution is to use 'thesaurus' option to indicate the dictionary. In that file (let's call it dict.txt), put entries like this

'alpha α'

Do setlocal thesaurus=dict.txt

When you do in insert mode

a CTRL-X CTRL-T

alpha will be inserted (a popup menu will be shown with the math line splitted into entries in the popup menu). Type again CTRL-X CTRL-T and

α will be inserted DELETING the previous typed word alpha.

ANOTHER SOLUTION (although is not exactly what questioned)

The solution above is a bit slower if you have to type faster (every time hitting CTRL-X CTRL-T). You can create two files called math_abb.txt and math_una.txt. One to set abbreviations and the other one for unset abbreviations. Then, load them with source command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I have no idea if such a plugin exists or even what keywords to use if I decided to search for it on vim.org.

But you can leverage Vim's dictionary completion as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17232648/546861) or use a snippet-expansion plugin like [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) or [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).

With dictionary completion, you would hit `<C-w><C-k>` to open a popup menu next to the cursor with all the items in your dictionary.

With SnipMate, for example, you could have all the "greek letter" snippets associated with the `grk` trigger. Typing `grk<tab>` in insert mode would show a list of all the greek letters for you to chose.

Comment: I have looked into the first post. The best solution is to use thesaurus option to indicate the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to do this with a markdown document, which is automatically folded using the vim-markdown plugin. Will probably work with any folding setup. It shows top-level sections on the left window and full doc on the right.

Procedure:

1. `:vsplit` *(and reduce left window length if desired)*
2. `:set foldlevel=0` in left window *(show fully collapsed)*
3. `:set foldlevel=999` in right window *(show fully expanded)*
4. `:windo set scrollbind cursorbind` *(this will set both variables on both windows)*

Now, when you navigate through sections in the left window, the right window will automatically sync position. You'll still need to jump back into the right window after navigating.